# How to know how many files are dragged and dropped on the application icon?

Tags: delphi

Name of the file that is dropped on the application icon are found in ParamStr(1).

But, how to know if there is more than one? Because, if there is more, then error message should be shown up, like: 'You can open only one picture!' or similar to that.

Comment: @Ken: That is an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Andreas: Yeah, I decided so too. By the time I got one ready, there were two others there. <g>

Comment: @SrdjanVukmirica: Thanks. Flávio beat me to posting an answer, so you correctly accepted his. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows just executes your program like this:

```
yourapp.exe "C:\file1.jpg" "C:\file2.jpg"
```

So each of these files can be found in `ParamStr(i)`, where `i` would go up to `ParamCount()` return value.

So you can just do for example:

```
procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ParamCount > 1 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('You can open only one picture!');
  end
  else
  begin
    MyOpen(ParamStr(1));
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

answer by example , every file will be a parameter

```
var
 i:Integer;

begin

  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(ParamCount));
  for I := 1 to ParamCount  do
    memo1.Lines.Add(paramstr(i))

end;
```